# Convert TSTAMP to human date and time

Tags: c#, modbus

I'm trying to read a device using Modbus RTU. The type of these fields is TSTAMP. When I read these fields, it returns an integer for each field. In the manual there is a table, with the addresses and types.

Each date consists of reading 2 addresses. For example: I want to read the "Volts" field so I need to read the address 8400-8402. Reading these fields returns the values **4622** and **9483**.

How do I convert these 2 integers to date and time format?

**MANUAL:**

[image]

**READING:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The format of a TSTAMP ought to be elsewhere in your manual, probably toward the end.

If I consult [this manual](https://www.electroind.com/products/Shark_250/pdf/manuals/Shark-250-Meter-Modbus-Manual_E169711.pdf), the format is

> TSTAMP: 3 adjacent registers, 2 bytes each. First (lowest-addressed) register high byte is year (0-99), low byte is month (1-12).
>
> Middle register high byte is day(1-31), low byte is hour (0-23 plus DST bit). DST (daylight saving time) bit is bit 6 (0x40).
>
> Third register high byte is minutes (0-59), low byte is seconds (0-59). For example, 9:35:07AM on October 12, 2049 would be 0x310A, 0x0C49, 0x2307, assuming DST is in effect

Comment: How to convert 4622 and 9483 (the reading return)? It would be Year 2046, Month 22, Day 94 and Hour 83.

Comment: Don't read them as decimal values.  They're stored as individual bytes.  For example, 4622 is 0x120E, and you'd read the bytes individually (0x12 = 18, 0x0E = 14).  Of course the fact that you only got two register values when you should be getting three indicates there's likely another issue involved.

Comment: My bad.. the reading positions are 8400-8402. So 1 position was missing. Now reading all 3 numbers, it returned: 4622, 9483, 3331. Reading as byte: 1814, 3711, 133. Following the rules of the manual that John posted, it would be: Year 2018, Month 14, Day 37, Hour 11 and Second 133. It still doesn't make sense, even reading as a byte.